# Select control does not have ItemSelected in dynamically created VBox UI5 application

Tags: sapui5

I have a select control inside a VBox which are created dynamically in Controller.
Even though I have used setSelectedItem, still the view shows select control with blank and on dropdown I see the value which is binding. This same function is used while "Create New record" and  "Edit existing record". If I make forceSelection = true, it shows the item (in edit) and also during create (I don't want this - as user can chose to keep it blank).

Why does the below code not assign the value as selected (so I don't have to use forceSelection = true) ?

Controller.js

```
    oNewVBox.insertItem(new sap.m.Label({
                text: "{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/labelText}",
                required: "{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/labelReq}"
            }));

            // If Defaults exist then Field is drodpown
            if (currentValue.DefaultValue !== "") {
                oNewField = new sap.m.Select({
                    enabled: "{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/fieldEnabled}",
                    forceSelection: true,
                    width: "90%",
                    // Add dropdoen Items
                    items: [new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                        key: "{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/DefaultValue}",
                        text: "{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/DefaultValue}"
                    })],
                    valueState: "{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/ValueState}",
                    valueStateText: "{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/ValueStateText}"
                });
                // Set key
                oNewField.setSelectedItem("{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/value}");
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure the key of selected item exists in your select control?

Comment: @MatthijsMennens  When I put debuuger, and see console after the last line, I see this:        
              
oNewField.getSelectedKey()    Answer:
"{order>/HeaderData/0/DefaultValue}"

Comment: @Rafael is right, you can only select an item in the control by passing its ID or the item itself.

Comment: @MatthijsMennens noted an it worked. But my issue is, same piece of code is used to create 6 Select boxes. When I change the value in any select, no event is fired. If it fires, I can see the getSource() and know which Select triggered. But how to fire that event. When I write  change="selectChanged" in select definition, it is not working.

Comment: I get an error in console. How to trigger the change?

Comment: Try someting like this:

Comment: var that = this;
   
   var oNewField = new sap.m.Select({
    enabled: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    width: "90%",
    change: function() {
     that.onChange();
    },
    items: [new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
     key: "key1",
     text: "key 1"
    }), new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
     key: "key2",
     text: "key 2"
    })]
   });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud pass the ID or the sap.ui.core.Item object to the setSelectedItem function. You cannot do a binding as you are trying to do there. You do data binding with properties or aggregations, but makes not sense to "bind an argument of a function".

From your code I guess you are trying to select your item using the Item 'key' that is stored in your 'order' model. So try to change this:

```
oNewField.setSelectedItem("{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/value}");
```

for this

```
var selectedKey = this.getView().getModel('order').getProperty("/" + Type + "/" + i + "/value")
oNewField.setSelectedKey(selectedKey); // Passing the Item 'key' as selector
//oNewField.setSelectedItem(selectedKey); // Only if in your model you have saved the sap.ui.code.Item ID
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. On the same scenario, another doubt. So this about function is creating 6 dropdowns in the view. How do I access them later? Like if the drop down value is changed by the user, how do I differentiate which select's change is triggered, as there are no ids. Also, if same piece of code is called 6 times with different odata binding values, how to even assign different ids to the select?

Comment: The event handler function usually receive the event object as parameter. So you can get the source that triggers the event handler function from there. for instance: `onSelectChange(oEvent){ var oSourceControl = oEvent.getSource() }`

Comment: I thought so, but how to I attach change event to the select. I tried to do it normally while creating the select as below, but even if I change, the function is not  called: oNewField = new sap.m.Select({
                    enabled: "{order>/" + Type + "/" + i + "/fieldEnabled}",
                    forceSelection: true,
                    change: "valueChanged",
                    width: "90%",
                    // Add dropdoen Items
                    items:

Comment: if I add change: valueChanged ( as shown in my comment), I get an error in console. How to trigger change?

Comment: try this: `change: this.valueChanged`

Comment: it works. Now my issue is how do I find the bindingContext. Following always shows undefined in the console. I tried to mention the model name as parameter, but still did not work. Now everything is set for me, except I am not finding the binding path. 
oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext()

Comment: You need to pass the model name. `oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext('order')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177929/discussion-between-thi-and-rafael-lopez-martinez).

Comment: And also, if you wanna use the `this` context inside the event handler, you need to bind it `change: this.valueChanged.bind(this)`

Comment: I did: var that = this.
and then  change: that.changeMethod

Is this not good?

Comment: Yes, it works as well ... There's always many ways to do things